# Getting a debug assertion error when calling GetDC() (MFC)

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-debugging

I'm making a MFC application using the Doc/View architecture with Visual Studio 2017, and for some reason I get that error whenever I call GetDC() inside this function:

```
void CDigitRecognizerView::ClearScreen(void)
{
    CDC* dc;
    dc = GetDC(); // debug assertion error here
    CBrush brush;
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(0xFFFFFF);
    dc->SelectObject(&brush);

    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);

    dc->FillRect(&rect, &brush);
    CDigitRecognizerDoc* pDocument = GetDocument();

    ReleaseDC(dc);
}
```

This is the message map macro defined in the app class:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDigitRecognizerApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_ABOUT, &CDigitRecognizerApp::OnAppAbout)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CWinApp::OnFileNew)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinApp::OnFileOpen)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_CLEARSCREEN, CDigitRecognizerView::ClearScreen)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

So whenever I select the "Clear Screen" option from the menu of the app, ClearScreen() gets called but I can't get the DC of the View, it crashes.

I have looked at the variables in the debugger and the window handle seems OK so I don't know really.

[image]

I am also wondering what other way I could call a function of the View class from the App class whenever I select a menu option because this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried tracing into `GetDC` to see exactly where it's crashing? P.S. What is the exact error, you didn't put it into the question?

Comment: Never tried tracing before so I don't know how to do that exactly. I tried stepping into it but I'm missing a module apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you get the `CWinApp` message-map pointing to a `CDigitRecognizerView` function? I think the "wizard" wouldn't do this. Did you add the handler manually?

As for accessing Doc/View instances from the `CWinApp` class, there are some functions available:

- `GetFirstDocTemplatePosition()` / `GetNextDocTemplate()`, members of `CWinApp` class. Alternatively you can simply store the `pDocTemplate` instance created in the `InitInstance()` function. Then call:
- `GetFirstDocPosition()` / `GetNextDoc()`, members of the `CDocTemplate` class, and finally:
- `GetFirstViewPosition()` / `GenNextView()`, members of the `CDocument` class

But this is normally not needed (the events could be handled in the Doc/View classes), unless you want to perform some operation(s) on all (or some of the) DocTemplate/Doc/View instances (which rather implies that you are developing an MDI application).

Comment: Yes I added it manually. I am making a SDI app. So how would handling menu selection be done without accessing the CView directly from the CWinApp?

Comment: This is really simple, go to the Class View tab, select the CDigitRecognizerView class, then in the Properties pane click the Events button, and add a handler there (COMMAND and possibly UPDATE_COMMAND_UI as well).

Comment: It's still going to have problems and it will probably crash at a later point. You are selecting a brush into a DC and deleting/destroying the DC before you select the old brush into the DC. In fact, you don't save the old brush to be able to select it back into the DC.